# Pandas pd.pivot_table where aggfunc returns a set or list of unique items within a subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, set, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I am looking for an efficient method to `pivot` or `groupby` a data frame where the output is the list of unique items in that subgroup. I am not interested in using loops and would prefer to retain the result as a data frame. Thank you in advance.

**Example df:**

| number | letter | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | a | apple |
| 101 | b | melon |
| 101 | a | peach |
| 201 | b | grape |
| 101 | b | orange |
| 101 | a | pear |
| 201 | b | apple |
| 201 | a | peach |

**My Code:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'number':['101','101','101','201','101','101','201','201'], 'letter': ['a','b','a','b','b','a','b','a'], 'fruit':['apple','melon','peach','grape','orange','pear','apple','peach'] })
    
pd.pivot_table(df, index='number', columns='letter', values='fruit', aggfunc='sum')
```

**Output:**

| letter | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **number** |  |  |
| 101 | appleapplepear | melonorange |
| 201 | peach | grapeapple |

---

**Desired Output:**

| letter | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **number** |  |  |
| 101 | [apple ,pear] | [melon ,orange] |
| 201 | [peach] | [grape ,apple] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) for the `aggfunc`, as follows:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='number', columns='letter', values='fruit', aggfunc=pd.unique)
```

Note that the output for a single item is not within a list.   Some people prefer this but see whether it fits your preference.

**Result:**

```
letter                     a                b
number                                       
101     [apple, peach, pear]  [melon, orange]
201                    peach   [grape, apple]
```

If you like to put single item also into a list, you can modify the call to [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) a bit, as follows:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='number', columns='letter', values='fruit', aggfunc=lambda x: pd.unique(x).tolist())
```

**Result:**

```
letter                     a                b
number                                       
101     [apple, peach, pear]  [melon, orange]
201                  [peach]   [grape, apple]
```

Thus, you have 2 choices of output layouts for single item now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, index='number', columns='letter', values='fruit', aggfunc=lambda x: list(set(x)))
letter                     a                b
number                                       
101     [apple, peach, pear]  [melon, orange]
201                  [peach]   [grape, apple]
```